# Django Timezone Configuration

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

My django project is correctly enable the timezone in settings.

However, the datetime field of Django ORM object is a naive datetime object as shown in Block 3.

The expected result should be same as the output of Block 4 without any manually conversion.

```py
In [1]: from django.conf import settings
   ...: settings.USE_TZ, settings.TIME_ZONE
Out[1]: (True, 'Asia/Hong_Kong')

In [2]: from qms.models import Quota

In [3]: q = Quota.objects.get(pk=1)
   ...: q.create_date, q.write_date
Out[3]:
(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 17, 37, 42, 489818),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 17, 37, 42, 489818))

In [4]: from django.utils import timezone
   ...: timezone.make_aware(q.create_date,timezone.utc), \
   ...: timezone.make_aware(q.write_date, timezone.utc)
Out[4]:
(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 17, 37, 42, 489818, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 17, 37, 42, 489818, tzinfo=<UTC>))
```

Record in SQL

| Column | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | 1 |
| create_date | 2021-03-10 17:37:42.489818+00 |
| write_date | 2021-03-10 17:37:42.489818+00 |
| name | email |

Django Model Definition

```py
class Quota(models.models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    write_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The PostgreSQL database schema and settings, Table "public.qms_quota"

| Column | Type | Modifiers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | integer | not null default nextval('qms_quota_id_seq'::regclass) |
| create_date | timestamp with time zone | not null |
| write_date | timestamp with time zone | not null |
| name | character varying(255) | not null |

```sql
SHOW TIMEZONE;
 TimeZone
----------
 UTC
```

Questions

1. **How can I get the timezone-aware datetime object directly without any conversion?**
2. **Or the manual conversion is expected ?**

Comment: This is unusual behavior, so I'm assuming that your application or database has changed at some point? Can you replicate this with a fresh database? Also, please show the actual database values (not the Python objects) for your example (`pk=1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root-cause is a bug from a connection pool library `django_postgrespool2==2.0.1`.

When you use the your connection engine with "django_postgrespool2", it will *NOT* correctly handle the timezone settings.   [Releated Issue](https://github.com/lcd1232/django-postgrespool2/issues/22)

## TLDR: use engine `django.db.backends.postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `django.utils.timezone.localtime` to convert the datetime received from the DB to localtime:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
q = Quota.objects.get(pk=1)
print(localtime(q.create_date), localtime(q.write_date))
```

Comment: i want to get the aware datetime object without any conversion